# Pagination with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, pagination

If I use this SQL, I get this records:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE

 ID        TITLE
----      -------
 23        title 1
 25        title 2
 31        title 3
 38        title 4
 43        title 5
....         ....
 178       title 69 
 189       title 70
```

If I use pagination, my SQL would be this:

```
SELECT *,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY news_date DESC, news_id DESC) AS Position
FROM news
ORDER BY news_date DESC, news_id DESC 
OFFSET 5 ROW FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;

 ID        TITLE       TOTAL      POSITION
----      -------     -------    ----------
 45        title 6      70           #6
 46        title 7      70           #7
 48        title 8      70           #8
 51        title 9      70           #9
 54        title 10     70           #10
```

Now, I would get the first 3 and last 3 values, and get the #27 (for example) with (#27+3 AND #27-3) because my ID is "127"(with #27 position).
I can make a partial SQL:

```
WITH NewsSql AS (
SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY new_date DESC,new_id DESC) AS Position
FROM news
)SELECT * FROM NewsSql 
WHERE Position<=3 OR Position>=Total-2 OR news_id=127

 ID        TITLE       TOTAL      POSITION
----      -------     -------    ----------
 23        title 1      70           #1
 25        title 2      70           #2
 31        title 3      70           #3
 127       title 27     70           #27
 175       title 68     70           #68
 178       title 69     70           #69
 189       title 70     70           #70
```

How can I add the records with position between #24 and #30?

PD: Sorry for my English

Comment: So, you're getting some kind of input from somewhere, that's 27 (or 127, not clear on that matter), and what you want as output are (always) the first 3 rows, then the row that corresponds with the input, plus the 3 rows either side of it, and (always) the last 3 rows, is that correct? What should happen if the input overlaps with the first or last requirements? Do the rows still only appear once?

Comment: Use `WHERE Position BETWEEN 24 and 30` ?? .....

Comment: My input will be an ID code (25,127, 178......), but I need the position to use `BETWEEN`. If the input overlaps with the first or last requiriments, only show that records. Actually there is no problem about that.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the question with this SQL:

```
WITH NewsSql AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY news_date DESC,news_id DESC) AS Position,
    (
        SELECT Pos 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                news_id AS NewsID,
                news_title,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY news_date DESC,news_id DESC) AS Pos
            FROM news
        ) news_pos
        WHERE news_pos.NewsID= <ID_input> 
    ) AS Actual
  FROM news
)
SELECT * FROM NewsSql 
WHERE 
    Position<=3 OR 
    Position>=Total-2 OR 
    news_id=127 OR 
    Position BETWEEN Actual-5 AND Actual+5
```